# Apache Airflow not scheduling tasks

Tags: python, python-2.7, airflow, macos-high-sierra, airflow-scheduler

I have installed apache-airflow (version v1.9.0) along with python 2.7. To test whether its installed properly I tried to trigger a tutorial DAG from the interactive view in browser. The interface shows that the DAG is running, but the scheduler doesn't show any activity.

Below are the steps I tried

1. Install airflow

```
pip install apache-airflow
```

2. Install crypto for setting encryption using fernet key

```
pip install apache-airflow[crypto]
```

3. Generate a fernet_key and add in airflow.cfg file:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
fernet_key= Fernet.generate_key()
print(fernet_key)
```

4. Initialise a airflow sqlite db

```
airflow initdb
```

5. Start the airflow webserver

```
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

6. Start the airflow scheduler in a different window

```
airflow scheduler
```

7. Trigger the `tutotial` DAG on the Airflow page at `localhost:8080`

After following these steps, I am not able to see any movement in my scheduler window, which just keeps me showing

```
INFO - Heartbeating the process manager
INFO - Heartbeating the executor
```

I have tried it running in the local environment as well as in a virtual environment. I have also tried running through `SequentialExecutor` and `LocalExecutor`

the task is not triggered even when I try to trigger it through the terminal by `airflow trigger_dag tutorial`

I am working on mac OS High Sierra Version 10.13.3

Comment: can you run following commands? `airflow list_dags` and `airflow list_tasks <dag_id>`

Comment: also can you test a task with the follwing.
`airflow test <dag_id> <task_id> 2018-06-06`

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default, all the dags will be paused at the start. You have to unpause the dags and trigger them.

Comment: dang I spent days trying to figure out why a dag wouldn't start before finding this.

Answer (score 1):

The switch next to each task is on "OFF" by default. that was it for me

Answer (score 0):

After triggering your dag you have to turn on your DAG as by default it is off. You can turn this on by using AIRFLOW UI.